# Changing Layout Background Colors in Java

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, background

I recently made an app with several XML layouts (and I gave them all very colorful backgrounds too!)  However, my friend noted it was a little 'too' colorful.

So, I decided to add a checkbox to the main.xml file, which is checked by default.  If unchecked, I want every background color to go black, my buttons' colors to change their background color from "@drawable/buttoncolor" to "@drawable/colorless", and all the text in the buttons to change to white ("#FFFFFF").  Then if checked again, the program should restore to default.

So the question is... how would I do this?  I already established something like this:

```
View colorBox = findViewById(R.id.noColor);
colorBox.setOnClickListener(this);
```

where colorBox is my checkbox.

And later on...

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    // (Other code I have here)
    case R.id.noColor:
        // Does something go here..?
        break;
    }
}
```

All help is appreciated.

(On a side note, this solution didn't work for me either: [How to change a TextView's background color with a color defined in my values/colors.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911614/how-to-change-a-textviews-background-color-with-a-color-defined-in-my-values-col))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
colorBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorless);
((TextView)colorBox).setTextColor(COLOR.WHITE);
```

you need to import java.awt.Color

Comment: Thanks, that works for the textboxes.  How do I change a whole layout's background to black though?

Comment: findViewById(R.id.layout).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
but obviously replace R.id.layout with the id you've given your layout

Answer (score 0):

Look for [setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) or [setBackgroundDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) and then call either of these methods on each view to change there background.