# Change background color of part of textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview with three lines, for example, name, phone and address. I want to distinguish third line, I want to add image there, get a round border for it and change background color. Is there a way I can do?

Comment: Can't you use several TextView ?

Comment: Maybe this can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911614/how-to-change-a-textviews-background-color-with-a-color-defined-in-my-values-co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an easy way, you can use 3 textviews like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Details" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phone" />

        <TextView
            android:background="#f00"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also see snapshot[image]

Answer (score 7):

To change a part of the background you'll need is a Spannable.

```
int startColor = 0; //the size that start the background color
int endColor = 100; //the size that ends the background color

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);

Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(" Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will automatically handle clicks on the Home");

spannable.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), startColor, endColor, 
                  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

If you want it clickable you can use:

```
spannable.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "link clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, startColor, endColor, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Font [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use either Spannable or you have to use Html. These both will work.

Html Example:

```
YOURTEXTVIEW.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='green'><b>" + YOUR BACKGROUND TEXT + "</b></font>" + "  "+ YOUR LONG LONG TEXT));
```

You have to just write Html for set background.

And for spannable you will get lots of data from Google.

Comment: I know how to set image with Html. And how I can use border with background color with it?

Comment: For that you have to learn a little Html, or ask any Html person, may be you will get better idea.

Comment: @praktik Html in TextView is pretty limited, so there's no way to achieve a border etc. as this would require CSS support. You really should go with the solution proposed by Bontok and use 3 separate TextViews.

Comment: Yeah it will fine finally, but this solution is for if you must need to do with one. Otherwise 3 textviews are fine at last.

Comment: Accept and upvote answer if you find it is useful for others;

Answer (score -1):

change the back ground like this

### customshape.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

      <solid android:color="your_back_ground_color" />  

        <corners android:radius="8dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="0.5dp"
            android:color="Border_color" >
        </stroke>

    </shape>
```

put this in res/drawable

in layout xml

```
  <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/customshape"
        android:textColor="your_color"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="your_text" />
```

and I hope if its overlaping with the textview the add padding on the custom layout.